# DigestUtils.md5 returning different values each call with the same string

Tags: jmeter, md5, digest

Why is this code Printing different results for each call?

```
log.info("String to MD5 ->" + FileContentRaw + "<-");
log.info("MD5 Result 1 Apache->" + org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5(FileContentRaw).toString() + "<-");
log.info("MD5 Result 2 Apache->" + org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5(FileContentRaw).toString() + "<-");
log.info("MD5 Result 3 Apache->" + org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5(FileContentRaw).toString() + "<-");
log.info("MD5 Result 4 Apache->" + org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5(FileContentRaw).toString() + "<-");
```

This is the result:

```
2016/11/21 11:22:29 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: String to MD5 ->{"type":"StatsReq","msg":[{"symList":["AAPL.O","MFFT.O"],"startDate":"2015-01-03","endDate":"2015-01-03","dataType":"trade","assetClass":"tmx","analytics":["VWAP","TWAP"],"startTime":null,"endTime":null,"granularity":null,"granularityUnit":null,"fill":null,"timeZone":null,"inputTimeZone":null,"outputTimeZone":null,"temporality":null}],"id":"gevv4nfhbul0rrhlcco2as63to","date":"Mon, 21 Nov 2016 11:22:29 EST"}<-

2016/11/21 11:22:29 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: MD5 Result 1 Apache->[B@49f63d7c<-

2016/11/21 11:22:29 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: MD5 Result 2 Apache->[B@182c34a7<-

2016/11/21 11:22:29 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: MD5 Result 3 Apache->[B@56b1896b<-

2016/11/21 11:22:29 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: MD5 Result 4 Apache->[B@355dc639<-
```

Comment: any feedback on answer ? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that other know they can trust it. thx

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that:

> [org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#md5(byte[]))(...)

Returns a byte[]

So you're doing a toString() on an array which returns the reference of this array, so even if the content of array is the same you get a different value for the Object reference each time.

You should display [org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#line.295)() which will give you the same value and which is a String.